Why do I keep getting page not found when I am literally using the link from supabase?
It is literally my first day using Supabase. I am trying to get it to update a database in Notion whenever the Supabase database is updated. However, I am getting an issue that says page not found%  when I am using the correct link that the website gave me. What is going wrong and how can I fix this issue?
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/x/sift@0.6.0/mod.ts";
import { config } from "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts";

// Load environment variables from .env file
const NOTION_API_KEY = Deno.env.get("NOTION_API_KEY");
const NOTION_DATABASE_ID = Deno.env.get("NOTION_DATABASE_ID");

// Check if environment variables are set
if (!NOTION_API_KEY || !NOTION_DATABASE_ID) {
  console.error("Missing Notion API Key or Database ID");
  serve(() => new Response("Missing Notion API Key or Database ID", { status: 500 }));
}

serve(async (req: Request) => {
  try {
    // Only allow POST requests
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
      console.log(`Received unsupported method: ${req.method}`);
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: "Method not allowed" }),
        { status: 405 }
      );
    }

    // Parse the incoming request payload
    const { record } = await req.json();
    if (!record || !record.id || !record.name || !record.phone) {
      console.error("Required fields are missing in the request record");
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: "Missing required fields in request" }),
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    console.log("Received record:", JSON.stringify(record, null, 2));

    // Prepare the data for Notion
    const notionData = {
      parent: { database_id: NOTION_DATABASE_ID },
      properties: {
        id: { title: [{ text: { content: record.id || "" } }] },
        name: { rich_text: [{ text: { content: record.name || "" } }] },
        phone: { rich_text: [{ text: { content: record.phone || "" } }] },
        region: { rich_text: [{ text: { content: record.region || "" } }] },
        created_at: { date: { start: record.created_at || "" } },
        agree: { checkbox: record.agree || false },
        done_contact: { checkbox: record.done_contact || false },
        done_meet: { checkbox: record.done_meet || false },
        memo: { rich_text: [{ text: { content: record.memo || "" } }] },
      },
    };

    // Send a POST request to Notion API
    const notionResponse = await fetch("https://api.notion.com/v1/pages", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${NOTION_API_KEY}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(notionData),
    });

    if (!notionResponse.ok) {
      const errorText = await notionResponse.text();
      if (notionResponse.status === 401) {
        console.error("Notion API Unauthorized:", errorText);
      } else {
        console.error("Notion API Error:", errorText);
      }
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: errorText }),
        { status: notionResponse.status }
      );
    }

    const notionResult = await notionResponse.json();
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ status: "success", notion_page_id: notionResult.id }),
      { status: 200 }
    );

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unexpected error:", error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: error.message }),
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
});


"I am getting an issue that says page not found%" -> Please read How to ask
